# Sorting using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I'm having a problem regarding sorting.

Data is like this

```
NSArray* testArr = @[@{@"key":@"aaa", @"value":@"asdfaf"},
                     @{@"key":@"baa", @"value":@"bsdfaf"},
                     @{@"key":@"!!aaa", @"value":@"adsfdfaf"},
                     @{@"key":@"123aaa", @"value":@"cecdfaf"},
                     @{@"key":@"@@#21", @"value":@"a42faf"},
                     @{@"key":@"ace", @"value":@"a123faf"},
                     @{@"key":@"321!!", @"value":@"123sdfaf"},
                     ];
```

And NSSortDescriptor is like this

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];        
NSSortDescriptor *sortUsingNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    NSStringCompareOptions comparisonOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch | NSForcedOrderingSearch | NSNumericSearch;
    NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, ((NSString *)obj1).length);

    return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:(NSString*) obj2 options:comparisonOptions range:stringRange locale:locale];
    }];
```

this is the result.

```
{
    key = "!!aaa";
    value = adsfdfaf;
},
    {
    key = "@@#21";
    value = a42faf;
},
    {
    key = 123aaa;
    value = cecdfaf;
},
    {
    key = "321!!";
    value = 123sdfaf;
},
    {
    key = aaa;
    value = asdfaf;
},
    {
    key = ace;
    value = a123faf;
},
    {
    key = baa;
    value = bsdfaf;
}
```

But I want to sort it like this

```
{
    key = aaa;
    value = asdfaf;
},
    {
    key = ace;
    value = a123faf;
},
    {
    key = baa;
    value = bsdfaf;
},
{
    key = 123aaa;
    value = cecdfaf;
},
{
    key = "321!!";
    value = 123sdfaf;
},
{
    key = "!!aaa";
    value = adsfdfaf;
},
{
    key = "@@#21";
    value = a42faf;
}
```

It is alphabet, number and special char sequence.
How can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid you will have to create your own comparator. Please look at this answer [Easy way to put blank strings at end of sort using NSSortDescriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743890/easy-way-to-put-blank-strings-at-end-of-sort-using-nssortdescriptor?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
NSArray* sortedArray = [inFileTypes sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: It is not working because ascending is NO. And if it is YES, result is same. Thanks:)

Comment: if you want reverse order Array object then [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/586483/2771713) will help you.